# What could be the reason for OpenLDAP replica to skip few items while synchronization

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have an OpenLdap cluster with 6 nodes, when an item is added/deleted in the master, the synchronization kicks in and the changes are replicated to other slave nodes in the cluster, but sometimes one of the slave cluster nodes (the same node all the time) misses the updates and hence there is a difference between this slave node and the rest of the slave nodes and the master, so sometimes when the request goes to the unsynchronized slave it yields invalid results.

In the problematic slave's ldap logs, there is no error information during this operation to the master which explains the miss, so cant figure out what has caused this problem, bringing down that slave and re-add does not help either.

Anyone has faced similar problem and figured out the cause ?

Comment: You need to go berserk with the logging. There are all kinds of additional logging you can configure, which are written into the DIT itself. I used OpenLDAP replication for several years in a row. I had occasional glitches but nothing systematic. Even if a slave drops a connection it should pick up where it left off.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.  Try Super User or maybe Server Fault, or even better an OpenLDAP mailing list (assuming it exist).

Comment: @user207421 : Thank you for responding. This happened in a production setup.

Similar to your experience, we too have been using OpenLDAP in the product for a couple of years now and we have not faced such issues so far in our lab, so could not conclude on the cause.

Comment: @Allan Wind: Thank you for your response.

As you mentioned, this is not a programming question, this is a problem occurred in a production LDAP cluster which is not related to our LDAP API usage. Will have to try the mailing list (looking for it).

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the query in OpenLDAP itself and they suggested to go for the upgrade as the version i am using is 2.4.44 which is couple of years old and looks like there have been many replication related fixes went in since 2.4.44

Below is the OpenLDAP forum link for the same:
https://bugs.openldap.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9701